# How come I can't ping my home computer?

Tags: firewall, ping, dmz

I'm trying to set up a vpn into my home computer in order to access files from wherever.  I have the home computer set up with a no-ip dynamic dns program so I can always connect, and have also tried using the actual ip address.  However, when I try to connect or even ping from anywhere outside of my house I can't get through.  I've tried putting that particular computer in the dmz, turned off the computers firewall and anti-virus, and I still don't get anything.  I have comcast as my home internet provider.  I have also tried from two different locations.  Are there any other solutions I can try or is comcast the issue?  I used to be able to do this when I ran a small web server at home for fun but now nothing works.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try plugging your computer directly into your modem without going through the router and testing the ping. If it works then, you know it is a router issue. If the problem persists, check your firewall (sometimes Norton/McAfee/etc have hidden firewalls running).

As far as I know Comcast would not block pings.

Comment: Ya I'm retarded.  I dug into the settings on my home router and found a setting that blocked pings.  All good now, so now I'm off to figure out if my vpn will connect.  If not, that's a whole other issue.  Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you computer is setup to reply to pings. In order to give you a more complete answer you would need to post your operating system.

Comment: Ref: Windows XP http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_und_icmp.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: If it is indeed Windows XP that would be it. I had a little list going for operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

1) Have you routed (via your router) the external traffic to the proper internal IP addresses?

2) Could your ISP be blocking certain ports?

The most basic test you can do is to set your DMZ to be your computer's internal IP, turn off Windows firewall and then try sending pings to your external IP and see if they come back.